# how to produce a break between float element

Tags: html, css

I'm try to format my photo wall by making every 1, 10,11,20,21,30,a big image,which ii 160*165, and between two big image,which are 85*80 there are 8 small images

the first five element works perfectly, like one big image, followed by 4 small images aligned like a big one//first line

I want to make second line the same pattern , but with 4 small coming first ,then comes the big image. but the situation is that it first display 3 small one, and start another line with the left small (what I want is to make these four small one to form like a square), I try to use a line break(after the position $i=7,17,27...), but its not working for float elements

```
<div style="width:350px"> 
    <?php
    $i=0;
    foreach($photo_array as $each){


        if($each!=''){
        $i++;

        $img_id=$username.$i;
         $pos=stripos($each,'&'); 
         $src=substr($each,$pos+1);

        $each_photo_string='user_data/post_img/'.$src;

        if(  (($i-1)%10==0) || ($i%10==0) ){
            echo '<img id="'.$img_id.'" class="p_photo_image" width="160"  height="165" style="margin-left:5px;float:left;"  alt="'.$each.'" src="'.$each_photo_string.'" >';
        }
        else{

                echo '<img id="'.$img_id.'" class="p_photo_image" width="85" height="80" style="float:left;margin-bottom:5px; margin-left:5px;"  alt="'.$each.'" src="'.$each_photo_string.'" >';
                if(($i%10)==7){
                    echo '<br>';
            }


        }

        }
    }

     ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `<br>` if you have got floated objects.

Try this instead of `<br>`:

```
<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:1px; margin:20px 0; display:block;"></div>
```

You need to use another floated object *(with margin attribute)* as a break

Comment: fyi `margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px` is the same as `margin: 20px 0px`

Comment: is not working , if I use this one,in the second line, it first displays 2 small one, then start a new line with 20px margin below, and continue to display another 2 and follow by the big one

Comment: If i change it into echo '<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:0px;  display:block;"></div>'; the first four small one dipslay perfectly, however, follow by big one with a margin at the top of it

Comment: @KesongTse and what happens if you remove `margin` attribut from my solution? = `<div style="float:left; width:100%; height:0px; display:block;"></div>`

Comment: the first four small one align like a square, and this is what I want, but the following big one , instead being displayed as the same height with the square before, it comes down a small image height and then display

Comment: I thing the div we use occupy the position that not allow the big one to be displayed as expected